# How to left join then get the latest row in second table using where date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Is anyone know how to query this example table?

[Images on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apVg1.jpg)

I think it is a left join from the table `branches` to the table `branch_operationals` which I need to put `where date` inside the query.

Here are the examples:

**TABLE `branches`**

| id | code | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T2QD5 | NewYork_Spot |
| 2 | MKGHB | London_Spot |
| 3 | IGHCZ | Miami_Spot |
| 4 | PJDSO | Tokyo_Spot |

**TABLE `branch_operationals`**

| id | branch_id | date | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2020-12-05 | closed |
| 2 | 2 | 2020-12-06 | closed |
| 3 | 3 | 2020-12-06 | open |
| 4 | 2 | 2020-12-06 | closed |
| 5 | 2 | 2020-12-06 | open |
| 6 | 1 | 2020-12-16 | closed |

**EXPECTED RESULT**

| id (from 'branches.id') | code | name | date | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T2QD5 | NewYork_Spot | 2020-12-09 | closed |
| 2 | MKGHB | London_Spot | 2020-12-09 | open |
| 3 | IGHCZ | Miami_Spot | 2020-12-09 | open |
| 4 | PJDSO | Tokyo_Spot | 2020-12-09 | null |

And here is my current query:

```
select * from `branches` left join `branch_operationals` on `branches`.`id` = `branch_operationals`.`branch_id` where (`date` = 2020-12-21)
```

However, it returns null (empty data). But when I remove the `where` statement, it shows all data from the table `branch_operationals` with each data from table `branches`.

Currently I am using Laravel 8, and here is my Laravel syntax:

```
$branches = Branch::leftJoin('branch_operationals','branches.id','branch_operationals.branch_id')->where(function($q) use($request){
    if($request->search){
        $q->where(function($q) use($request){
            $q->where('code','like','%'.$request->search.'%');
            $q->orWhere('name','like','%'.$request->search.'%');
        });
    }

    if($request->date_filter){
            $q->where('date',$request->date_filter);
    }else{
            $q->where('date',\Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateString());
    }
})->get();
```

I need the query syntax or the Laravel Eloquent syntax.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can provide you the query syntax which is normal `LEFT JOIN`.

The issue with your query is that you are doing `INNER JOIN` by applying the condition on the Left joined table in the `WHERE` clause. You can achieve the desired result as follows:

```
select * from
(select b.*, bo.*,  -- use the needed column names with proper alias here. I have used *
        row_number() over (partition by b.id order by bo.date desc) as rn
  from branches b 
  left join branch_operationals bo on b.id = bo.branch_id and date <= 2020-12-21) t 
where rn = 1
```

Comment: i've tried your query, put its return = all data from 'branches' + null data from 'branch_operationals', sir

Comment: Ok, It means there is no data in the branch_operationals table with given date.

Comment: nah, what i need is getting the 1 last result of each 'branches' from branch_operationals

Comment: Done!! check the answer now!!

Comment: its return #1060 - Duplicate column name 'id'

Comment: Yes, You need to use the name of columns instead of * for b.* and bo.*

Comment: like this ? select b.*,bo.* from
(select b.*, bo.*,  -- use the needed column names with proper alias here. I have used *
        row_number() over (partition by b.id order by bo.date desc) as rn
  from branches b 
  left join branch_operationals bo on b.id = bo.branch_id and date <= 2020-12-21) t 
where rn = 1

Comment: replace `b.*, bo.*,` with the needed columns like `b.id, bo.date, ...`

Comment: here my current query @Popeye

select * from
(select b.name, bo.date, bo.status,  -- use the needed column names with proper alias here. I have used *
        row_number() over (partition by b.id order by bo.date desc) as rn
  from branches b 
  left join branch_operationals bo on b.id = bo.branch_id and date <= 2020-12-21) t 
where rn = 1

and here the result https://imgur.com/a/NpyCvqp

Comment: i really need your help sir Popeye :) im glad for it

Answer (score 0):

**maybe it will work for you**

```
select b.id ,b.code,b.name ,'2020-12-06' date ,o.status from branch b 
left join  ( select  bo.id, bo.branch_id, bo.date, bo.status from
  (select branch_id , max(id) id  from branch_operationals where date='2020-12-06' group by branch_id ) as tmp
  join branch_operationals bo on bo.id=tmp.id ) as o on b.id=o.branch_id
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/NpyCvqp here is your result sir,,

Comment: '2020-12-06' is input  please cheange it